# Top padding does not appear

Tags: html, css

I'm in the middle of designing a WP theme. I've decided to make links in the header as they are in the image. However, I couldn't make the bluish gradient filled area filled with black background (I used that fancy gradient for just pointing the issue). Called charming `.current` class to make this achieved, it is basically:

```
.current {background-color: black; color: rgb(242, 245, 238); padding-top: 65px;}
```

Also image: [image]

I did **NOT** used CSS-reset, I checked `overflow` attributes for encapsulating divs of list, nothing worked.

HTML code:

```
<div id="container" class="">
    <div id="header" class="shadow">
        <div id="logoContainer">
            <span class="helper"></span><img src="img/tdw_logo_serif.png" alt="The Digital Warehouse">
            <div id="links">
                <ul class="helper">
                    <li><span class="helper"></span>HOME</li>
                    <li class="current"><span class="helper"></span>BLOG</li>
                    <li><span class="helper"></span>PORTFOLIO</li>
                    <li><span class="helper"></span>CONTACT</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#container {
}
#header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: rgb(242, 245, 238);
    color: rgba(5, 0, 18, 1.00);
    z-index: 100;
}   .willStick {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 65px;
}   .didStick {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#logoContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
#logoContainer img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
    .helper {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
#links {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: visible;
}
    #links ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-family: "jaf-bernino-sans-condensed", "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        list-style-type: none;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    #links li {
        width: 90px;
        height: 35px;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a specificity issue - try

```
 #links li.current etc.
```

```css
#container {
}
#header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: rgb(242, 245, 238);
    color: rgba(5, 0, 18, 1.00);
    z-index: 100;
}   .willStick {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 65px;
}   .didStick {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#logoContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
#logoContainer img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
    .helper {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
#links {
    position: relative;
    /*float:right;*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: visible;
}
    #links ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.7em;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-family: "jaf-bernino-sans-condensed", "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        list-style-type: none;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    #links li {
        width: 90px;
        height: 35px;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: visible;
    }

#links li.current {background-color: black; color: rgb(242, 245, 238); padding-top: 65px;}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="">
    <div id="header" class="shadow">
        <div id="logoContainer">
            <span class="helper"></span>
            <div id="links">
                <ul class="helper">
                    <li><span class="helper"></span>HOME</li>
                    <li class="current"><span class="helper"></span>BLOG</li>
                    <li><span class="helper"></span>PORTFOLIO</li>
                    <li><span class="helper"></span>CONTACT</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```